# Weird ball dropping in water sound in Ubuntu

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I've got a remote machine that seems to somewhat regularly output this weird artifact sound. It sounds like something like a ball or bucket dropping into water.

When I record 2 seconds of audio using `arecord -d 2 -r 48000 -f s16 out.wav`, for the most part the recording is perfect, but once every 10 or 20 times it has this problem. Here's an [example output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/447pt8iyvuc5v7l/bucket_drop_sound.wav?dl=0).

I have several machines that all seem to have this issue, and some other machines that don't. This odd artifact always sounds the same. It happens when audio is playing and also several seconds after audio has stopped playing.

Where is this sound coming from, and how do I stop it?

Comment: do you have another sound clip? ... the one you provided does not have any unusual sounds ... or provide another clip without the artifact

Comment: It's about 1.5 seconds out of the 2 seconds of the clip. It sounds very similar to /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg, which makes me think that's where the sound is coming from. Here's a converted mp3 of the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jd5azfb97cbxj9z/bell.mp3?dl=0

Comment: If its gtk remote, sounds come from libcanberra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you're getting is an alert sound like this one: /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/bell.ogg. Here's a [converted mp3 of the file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jd5azfb97cbxj9z/bell.mp3?dl=0) so that you can listen to it.

I'm not sure why you're getting these sounds, but if you [turn off alerts](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uww43i030puypq0/Screenshot%202020-03-20%2013.38.30.png?dl=0), this will probably make that sound go away.

It looks like you're also getting artifacts when the system bells happen. Something like [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574021/crackling-when-recording-audio) may be relevant.

Note that if you play some other audio and make an alert happen, even if alerts are turned off, you'll probably get a crackling sound! It seems that Ubuntu decides to play a "silent" sound, instead of not playing anything at all. And a "silent" sound mixed with some other audio will produce a crackle, if you're having issues like the question linked above.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this could be your "terminal bell" sound. Go to your terminal's Preferences section and disable the "Terminal bell" checkbox under Sound in your Profile's section.

Comment: I don't have a GUI terminal open in Ubuntu, but turning off all alerting bells seems partly helpful (https://www.dropbox.com/s/uww43i030puypq0/Screenshot%202020-03-20%2013.38.30.png?dl=0)

Comment: You can disable it without the GUI. Can you add `bind 'set bell-style none'` to your `~/.bashrc` file?

Comment: I mean to say that I don't think the terminal is the issue because there is no GUI terminal application running -- this would be the only way I think that the bell would come about. I'd be surprised if Ubuntu was making a sound because I was ssh'd into the machine.

Comment: Right. Why did you say that turning off all the alerts was partly helpful? Did it change the output you were getting?

Comment: It did, I'm still getting artifacts but not the ball dropping sound anymore. I'll just answer this question with that knowledge though, and research/ask another question about the audio artifacts. Thank you for the alert idea!