# Audio crackling on a vanilla AWS Ubuntu Server

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

## Problem

When I set up a brand new AWS Ubuntu 18.04 server (no sound card), it makes crackling noises in the audio. I'm using `arecord` to get audio from it. When I play more than one stream of audio, I hear a crackle for 200ms or so. What could be the issue?

## Test Case

- In my first terminal: `arecord -d 10 -r 48000 -f s16 out.wav`
- In my second terminal: `aplay 1khz.wav` (This is a [1khz sine wave](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3y5ehx8bli219by/1khz.wav?dl=0))
- In my third terminal: I start and stop aplay twice with a [2khz sine wave](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q5789augpff7hlm/2khz.wav?dl=0)

You'll here 4 separate crackles in the [out.wav](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xg8iy7mvnpkz47f/interacting_sine_1khz_2khz.wav?dl=0) here. There are 4 because I start twice and stop twice the 2khz sine wave.

## What I've tried so far

- Changing tsched as [mentioned here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling).
- [Suggestions from PulseAudio](https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio#Stuttering_and_audio_interruptions) related to stuttering
- I've heard that changing values in alsamixer could help, but I can't get it running, I think because the default settings don't work when a sound card is missing.

Comment: If your server doesn't have any soundcards, which ALSA devices are you using for that? snd-aloop? Or some Pulseaudio source/sink? What happens if you use `parecord`/`paplay` instead, if you are using Pulseaudio anyway?

Comment: `pavucontrol` says that the output is `dummy output`. `aplay -l` says there are no sound cards. This is a vanilla 18.04 AWS machine otherwise, I think. When using `parecord` / `paplay`, I get output, but there's something weird where the sound stops and starts during the recording at unexpected times.